# sshfs empty the source path with -o nonempty

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I came across a strange mistake, I have some data on `machine1` at

```
/temp/user1/data/
```

I want to share it with another `machine2`, so I created same directory as

```
mkdir /temp/user1/data/
```

then on machine1, I do

```
sshfs /temp/user1/data user1@machine2:/temp/user1/data
```

it prompts

```
fuse: mountpoint is not empty
fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option
```

then I do

```
sshfs -o nonempty /temp/user1/data user1@machine2:/temp/user1/data
```

suddenly, my data on `machine1` under `/temp/user1/data` are all gone, leaving an empty folder! all data lossed! what is wrong, can I got my data back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've mounted the remote machine's (empty) `/temp/user1/data` over the local machine's `/temp/user1/data`. All should be good if you simply unmount the SSHFS mount (using `fusermount`, since `sshfs` uses `fuse` under the hood).

Ex. we have a non-empty local directory

```
$ ls vm
somefile
```

then we mistakenly mount a remote directory over it:

```
$ sshfs vm vm:/home/steeldriver/dir
fuse: mountpoint is not empty
fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option
$ sshfs -ononempty vm vm:/home/steeldriver/dir
```

Now when we list `vm`, we see the contents of the remote `dir` instead:

```
$ ls vm
$
```

but if we unmount the SSHFS filesystem the local directory contents become visible again:

```
$ fusermount -u vm
$ ls vm
somefile
```

Comment: Thank you, but in my case, how do I mount a  directory with same path on machine2? I thought `sshfs source-paht target-path` is the syntax.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think you can *directly* "push" a local directory to a remote mount point like that - you'll either need to mount `user1@machine1:/temp/user1/data` to `/temp/user1/data` **from** machine2, or do something like this: [Reverse SSHFS mounts (fs push)](https://blog.dhampir.no/content/reverse-sshfs-mounts-fs-push)